# IF Inside a SELECT From XML

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to do a little bit different SELECT in a **SQL Server 2008**. I need to import a XML file to a table, but first i must to do some checking.

When I do the `SELECT` on XML, I need to check if the XML line already exists on the table, using the the columns `ViagemID` and `Data` from table as PK. If exists I need to update the line with information read from the XML, if not, I just need to insert in table.

XML line example:

```
<viagem id="0000EPN" date="2013-01-01T00:00:00" type="EXTRA" 
        status="NORMAL" modalid="IPANEM" fleetid="B200" 
        departuretime="2013-04-01T00:00:00" arrivaltime="2013-01-01T00:20:00" 
        maxpasg="2000" locationid="XX" codredlinha="0007" />
```

Code:

```
SELECT @ViagemID = r.value('(@id)[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)'), @Data =   CAST(CONVERT(datetime,r.value('(@date)[1]', 'datetime')) as float),    
        @Extra = CASE (r.value('(@type)[1]', 'VARCHAR(15)')) WHEN 'EXTRA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, @FleetID = r.value('(@fleetid)[1]', 'VARCHAR(15)'),
        @Partida = r.value('(@departuretime)[1]', 'datetime'),  @Chegada = r.value('(@arrivaltime)[1]', 'datetime'), @Capacidade = r.value('(@maxpasg)[1]', 'int'),
        @LocationID = r.value('(@locationid)[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'), @CodLinha = r.value('(@codredlinha)[1]', 'int')       

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.ImportacaoXML WHERE ViagemID = @ViagemID AND Data = @Data)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.ImportacaoXML SET ViagemID = @ViagemID, Data = @Data, Extra = @Extra, FleetID = @FleetID, Partida = @Partida, 
            Chegada = @Chegada, Capacidade = @Capacidade, LocationID = @LocationID, CodLinha = @CodLinha
            WHERE ViagemID = @ViagemID AND Data = @Data
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.ImportacaoXML VALUES(@ViagemID, @Data, @Extra, @FleetID, @Partida, @Chegada, @Capacidade, @LocationID, @CodLinha)       
    END

FROM (SELECT CAST(x AS XML) FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '\\10.16.68.253\XXXXx\Xxxx.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)) AS T(x)    
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/root/viagem') AS X(r);
```

But I keep getting a error in last `FROM` line (incorrect syntax near AS).

I could use a `SELECT` inside a if statement, but I need to read all XML, a this will stop the execution. Afterwards, I'll need to add more IFs statements.

Note 1: I'm new in SQL, sorry if about any crap.

Note 2: I'm concerned about the performance too, because I'm not sure if this code is the best program practice, and my table I'll grow a lot.

Comment: This SQL as posted is not valid - it won't even pass a syntax check... first off: did you **declare** all those SQL variables? Also: shouldn't the `SELECT` and the `FROM....` be together - before the whole `IF EXIST(...)` block??

Comment: I just removed the variables declaration. And the XML part it's working. If i use the the IF EXIST after the FROM clause it's get the last line of XML.

Comment: It's really not quite clear what you're trying to do - also: could you provide a sample XML and explain **what** you want to extract from that XML into your SQL Server tables??

Comment: Just updated. It's fairy simple. Read XML: already on table ? Update it (even if the data is the same), if not, insert. The problem is how to struct the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on SQL Server 2008, I would probably use a `MERGE` statement:

- parse your XML lines into columns in a sub query
- `MERGE` into the target table with the following rules:

  - if no match exists in the target table - then insert the new row into the target
  - when a row already exists - just update it

For this, I'd use something like this here:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.ImportacaoXML AS Tgt    
USING (SELECT 
          ViagemID = r.value('(@id)[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)'), 
          Data = CAST(r.value('(@date)[1]', 'datetime') as float),    
          Extra = CASE r.value('(@type)[1]', 'VARCHAR(15)') WHEN 'EXTRA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
          FleetID = r.value('(@fleetid)[1]', 'VARCHAR(15)'),
          Partida = r.value('(@departuretime)[1]', 'datetime'),  
          Chegada = r.value('(@arrivaltime)[1]', 'datetime'), 
          Capacidade = r.value('(@maxpasg)[1]', 'int'),
          LocationID = r.value('(@locationid)[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'), 
          CodLinha = r.value('(@codredlinha)[1]', 'int') 
        FROM 
           (SELECT CAST(x AS XML) FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'D:\Temp\Test.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(X)) AS T(x)    
        CROSS APPLY 
            x.nodes('/root/viagem') AS X(r)) AS Source 
    ON Tgt.ViagemID = Source.ViagemID AND Tgt.Data = Source.Data

WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE 
        SET Tgt.ViagemID = Source.ViagemID, Tgt.Data = Source.Data, 
            Tgt.Extra = Source.Extra, Tgt.FleetID = Source.FleetID, 
            Tgt.Partida = Source.Partida, Tgt.Chegada = Source.Chegada, 
            Tgt.Capacidade = Source.Capacidade, Tgt.LocationID = Source.LocationID, 
            Tgt.CodLinha = Source.CodLinha

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN     
    INSERT (ViagemID, Data, Extra, FleetID, Partida, Chegada, Capacidade, LocationID, CodLinha)
    VALUES (Source.ViagemID, Source.Data, Source.Extra, Source.FleetID, Source.Partida, Source.Chegada, Source.Capacidade, Source.LocationID, Source.CodLinha)
;
```

Comment: It's works. But can i use, for example, another select inside "Matched" clause ? Because i need to do another checking if it's matched, and a different one for "Not Matched". I'm searching on google, but i wanna ask here too.

Comment: @Juliano: no - inside the `WHEN MATCHED` you can **only** have an `UPDATE` or an `INSERT` (or a `DELETE`) statement - nothing else. [Read more about the `MERGE` statement here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/) - you *can* add a second `WHEN MATCHED` clause that has an additional condition on it - see the article I linked to for details